# I am a newbie to nhibernate fluent mappings. Can the HasManytoMany mapping be set only on one side of the relationship?

Tags: c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I created a many to many realtionship for 2 entities. But the mapping was only set on one side.  for example OrderMap class:

```
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Fields)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .ChildKeyColumn(ColumnNames.Field_Id)
            .ParentKeyColumn(ColumnNames.Order_Id)
            .LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table(TableNames.Order_Fields_Join);
```

But the other side ie for FieldMap class. I did not specify this mapping. Nhibernate is throwin errors as of now and I am no sure if it is because of this. Can you let me know if this is correct? 
My nhibernate errors are : "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not nessesary to map the ManyToMany on both sides, it is perfectly legal as you posted. The error you are getting is because you have want to save/update/delete two different objects with the same Identifier which indicates a bug hence NHibernate throws. Post the code which throws the exception.

Comment: I found the solution to this. As you mentioned I figured out It was not needed to map many to many on both sides. The error was because I was trying to add new child to the parent object instead of getting that child from the database repository and then assigning to the parent. Now it is working. Thanks